# How to extract a formatted string using regex in Python?

Tags: python, regex, extract

I am trying to find a regex in Python3 that extract a formatted string from input text :
The general format of the string is : 4 uppercase caracters followed by 3 numbers

Input :

```
"JFFC002    /0 EXÉRÈSE LÉS. RÉTROPÉRIT. COELIO 
KFFA001 /0 EXÉRÈSE T. PARAPHARYNGIENNE CERV.TOMIE LACA004   /0 O.S FRAC. ANT. SINUS FRONTAL AB. CORONAL LACA014 /0 O.S FRAC. BILAT. ANT. SINUS FRONTAL AB. CORONAL "
```

Output :

```
['JFFC002' , 'KFFA001' ,'LACA004', 'LACA014' ]
```

I appreciate your help!

Comment: Why don't you want LACA004? Seems like a valid output also for the given requirements.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? This is a rather basic pattern...

Comment: @Eraklon thank you i made an edit

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) with the following pattern:

```
s = '''"JFFC002 /0 EXÉRÈSE LÉS. RÉTROPÉRIT. COELIO
KFFA001 /0 EXÉRÈSE T. PARAPHARYNGIENNE CERV.TOMIE LACA004   /0 O.S FRAC. ANT. SINUS FRONTAL AB. CORONAL LACA014 /0 O.S FRAC. BILAT. ANT. SINUS FRONTAL AB. CORONAL "'''

import re

re.findall(r'[A-Z]{4}[0-9]{3}', s)
# ['JFFC002', 'KFFA001', 'LACA004', 'LACA014']
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/qxJuck/1)

- Match a single character present in the list below `[A-Z]{4}`

  - `{4}` Quantifier — Matches exactly 4 times
  - `A-Z` a single character in the range between `A` (index 65) and `Z` (index 90) (case sensitive)
- Match a single character present in the list below `[0-9]{3}`

  - `{3}` Quantifier — Matches exactly 3 times
  - `0-9` a single character in the range between `0` (index 48) and `9` (index 57) (case sensitive)